# Equivalence Relation

Tags: relations

Let S be equivalence relation defined on $\{x : x ∈ \mathbb{R},\ 0 ≤ x ≤ 5\} $defined by $xSy$ if and only if $[x] = [y]$. What are the equivalence classes of $S$?

Note: $[q]$ is defined to be the smallest integer greater than or equal to $q$. You can think of it as “$q$ rounded up”. You don’t need to prove that $S$ is an equivalence relation.

My answer is as follows but i am not sure if this is what they are looking for:

Equivalence classes of $S$ = $\{[0, 1), [1,2), [2,3), [3,4), [4,5)\}$

Comment: `the smallest integer greater than or equal to q` Then $\lceil 0 \rceil = 0$ while $\lceil 0.5 \rceil = 1\,$, so $0$ and $0.5$ do not belong into the same equivalence class $[0,1)\,$.

Comment: Your equivalence classes don't cover all elements of $S$,

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. The interval should be closed on the right, and you left out $5$. The equivalence classes are:
$$S= \left\{ {0}, (0,1], (1,2], (2,3], (3,4], (4,5] \right\}$$